# Binding DataGridView to data from different entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, binding, datagridview

I'm trying to show data from two related entities in a DataGridView. I know I could just select the values like this:

```
  from tasks in context.TaskSettings
     join train in context.Trainings on tasks.TrainingID equals train.TrainingID
     where tasks.TrainingID == task
           select new {TrainingName = train.TrainingName,  
                       DriversNeeded = tasks.DriversNeeded, 
                       EmployeesPerSupervisor = tasks.EmployeesPerSupervisor};
```

But that gives me immutable values and my interest is showing those values in a DataGridView so the user can just edit the values and click Save Changes.

I've tried this other approach

```
ObjectQuery<TaskSetting> trainingSettings = 
    (ObjectQuery<TaskSetting>)context.TaskSettings.Where(t => t.TrainingID == task);
dgvTask.DataSource = trainingSettings.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

but that just puts the whole Training entity in a single column

I want to be able to, at least, get the training name from the Training entity and still be able to make changes and update the Data Context accordingly. I wanted to post pictures to be more helpful, but this is my fist question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you better implement the [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) so that you manage the internal editing by binding both entities to single properties on the Mediator. Then you bind your DataGridView to the Mediator and let it to manage the custom proper updates on the respective entities.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the entity framework and I'm not sure how to use the Mediator Pattern. I have tried to do something similar with a "custom object". But I got stuck on the mapping-back-to-the-entities part.

Comment: @Yoinazek Basically I'm talking about a middle C# class, which not being an entity, act as if it were. Why? To give your UI the binding to both properties, from different entities.

Comment: And this middle class will be in charge of getting/setting values and doing the mapping back to the entities. Got it. Just need to figure out how to do it, hehe. Thanks